# Curl is enable but didnot return value

Tags: php, curl

I have installed curl. and configuration on my system is

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.35.0
Age 3
```

I have write code in my project is :

```
 $curl = curl_init();                   
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ; 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,6); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields ); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);          
 $curl_execute = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
```

Its not giving me value on my local machine while working fine on server. What is problem? 
My PHP version is

```
5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
```

I am using ubuntu 13.10
what is problem with my local machine? what i am missing. please suggest what to do?

Edit :
If i missed any information to write, please inform me.. i am using curl very first time.

Comment: You `echo`'ing out `$curl_execute` ? Cause the data should be in there.

Comment: echo $curl_execute; should show you what it returned..!

Comment: yes.. i checked here its return me bool(false). it should contain some value

Answer (score 0):

At first define the URL and post values correctly, I have added examples, please try this:

```
// define url examples
$submit_url = 'http://localhost/phptest/service.php';

// post fields examples
$postfields = 'name=foo&pass=bar&format=json';

// Start the process:
$curl = curl_init();

// Tell cURL to fail if an error occurs:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);

// Allow for redirects:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

// Assign the returned data to a variable:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Set the timeout:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

// Use POST:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Set the POST data:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);

// Execute the transaction:
$result = curl_exec($curl);

// Close the connection:
curl_close($curl);

// Print the results:
print_r($result);
```

Comment: var_dump($result), still giving me bool(false);

Comment: did you assign the url and post data correctly, please double check.

Comment: yes, it is, because same code is on server is working and also on others system. But not on mine.

Comment: can you send the url and post data ?

Comment: can you show the url and some post data what you are using for cURL

Comment: aahh.. i am really sorry , i cant send you that. but its a login process.